# Is it possible to run code after finishing a locust instance?

Tags: python, locust

Let's say this is the primary file I would run in terminal i.e `locusts -f main.py`. Is it possible to have it also run code after the locust instance is terminated or when time limit is reached? Possibly a cleanup script or sending the csv reports generated somewhere.

```
class setup(HttpUser):
     wait_time = between(3, 5)
     host = 'www.example.com'
     tasks = [a, b, c...]

#do something after time limit reached
```

Comment: Can't we specify events for test start and end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `test_stop` event (https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html) as well as a `quitting` event (https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.quitting) you can use for this purpose.